# Can we execute java program via node js api?

Tags: node.js, encryption, jar

I have a NodeJS api which takes data array and create xls file. That xls file need to be encrypted by a third party software. Right now we are doing it manually. For that we have a banking encryption software which is very simple and only ask two things input folder path and output folder path. After providing both paths to the software when we press encrypt button. The software encrypt the file inside input folder and save it in output folder.

We have no clue the encryption key use by that third party software.

Is there any way we can execute software (software is a jar file) and get the encrypted file via api.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I did in my past that simply invoked java command via nodejs child process, you can refer the official document https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: as I told, yes you can invoke java.exe from node.js and get the outcome of execution, I did that in the past for Excel file processing, write a java code and inherit the classes to invoke the encryption code and pass all three parameters via command line, so that you don't have to launch the UI

Comment: but that's a third party software which I want to execute. not my own java code

Comment: yes I know, as you are deriving the classes you are not tampering the code, you are safe, you are simply avoiding a GUI launch thats all, identify the class name which has methods using javap.exe and you can honestly invoke that method from any other java code, it is not necessary to launch the UI, use `jar tf AESEncrypter.jar` and see the files and use `javap` command to list all methods

Comment: I will give it a try for sure. Thank you so much

Comment: sure you can do, please don't share the file structure or function names anywhere, never do that

Comment: are we able to see the code inside that class file ?

Comment: i run that command jar tf AESEncrypter.jar and now able to see multiple files but i can't code any of it. how am i supposed to run this code without gui ?